# Error while deploying dialog flow sample code

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am trying to deploy sample weather dialog flow chat bot,

I am deploying it as per instruction given in dialog flow manual

for deploying index.js I am using following command

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloHttp --stage-bucket weather-example --trigger-http
```

after deploying file I get following error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named helloHttp
```

I dont know how to resolved it, I am new to google cloud and dialog flow,

here is my index.js file I just added my whether api key

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');

const host = 'api.worldweatheronline.com';
const wwoApiKey = 'MY wheather key';

exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res) => {
  // Get the city and date from the request
  let city = req.body.queryResult.parameters['geo-city']; // city is a required param

  // Get the date for the weather forecast (if present)
  let date = '';
  if (req.body.queryResult.parameters['date']) {
    date = req.body.queryResult.parameters['date'];
    console.log('Date: ' + date);
  }

  // Call the weather API
  callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the weather API to Dialogflow
  }).catch(() => {
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the weather but I hope it's good!` });
  });
};

function callWeatherApi (city, date) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create the path for the HTTP request to get the weather
    let path = '/premium/v1/weather.ashx?format=json&num_of_days=1' +
      '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(city) + '&key=' + wwoApiKey + '&date=' + date;
    console.log('API Request: ' + host + path);

    // Make the HTTP request to get the weather
    http.get({host: host, path: path}, (res) => {
      let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
      res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; }); // store each response chunk
      res.on('end', () => {
        // After all the data has been received parse the JSON for desired data
        let response = JSON.parse(body);
        let forecast = response['data']['weather'][0];
        let location = response['data']['request'][0];
        let conditions = response['data']['current_condition'][0];
        let currentConditions = conditions['weatherDesc'][0]['value'];

        // Create response
        let output = `Current conditions in the ${location['type']} 
        ${location['query']} are ${currentConditions} with a projected high of
        ${forecast['maxtempC']}°C or ${forecast['maxtempF']}°F and a low of 
        ${forecast['mintempC']}°C or ${forecast['mintempF']}°F on 
        ${forecast['date']}.`;

        // Resolve the promise with the output text
        console.log(output);
        resolve(output);
      });
      res.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(`Error calling the weather API: ${error}`)
        reject();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

can you please tell me whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As per you ***index.js*** file, you are exporting **weatherWebhook** named javascript function, so you should either put value of deploy function name attribute of `deploy` command of GCloud beta functions same as exported method name because by default when a Google Cloud Function is triggered, it executes a JavaScript function with the same name or if it cannot find a function with the same name, it executes a function named `function`.

For this your command would be, try this

```
gcloud beta functions deploy weatherWebhook --stage-bucket weather-example --trigger-http
```

**OR**

you can use **--entry-point** argument to tell gcp which function would be the entry point for your Google Cloud Function, if you want different name for your deployment.

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloHttp  --entry-point weatherWebhook  --stage-bucket weather-example --trigger-http
```

For more info about Google cloud function `deploy` command, [click here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy)

Comment: Hello Akshay, Thanks for answering but I got error due to I am deploying it with wrong way, correct way is gcloud beta functions deploy weatherWebhook --stage-bucket weather-example --trigger-http

Answer (score 0):

Hello friends I mistakenly using wrong deployment url,
Correct url is a follows:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloHttp  --entry-point weatherWebhook  --stage-bucket weather-example --trigger-http
```

Comment: but this is i already included in my answer , you can see 2nd part of answer.